# How do I check if a key exists in any of the dictionaries inside an array?

Tags: shopify, liquid

Is it possible to check if any of the dictionaries contains a specific key, preferably without looping through them? I got an array (`cart.items`) returned that looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "line_level_discount_allocations": [],
    "line_level_total_discount": 0,
    "selling_plan_allocation": {
      "price_adjustments": [
        {
          "position": 1,
          "price": 9500
        }
      ],
      "price": 9500,
      "compare_at_price": 9500,
      "per_delivery_price": 9500,
      "selling_plan": {
        "id": "xxxxx",
        "name": "Ships every 1 month",
        "description": null,
        "options": [
          {
            "name": "1 Month(s), 2 Month(s), 3 Month(s)",
            "position": 1,
            "value": "1 Month(s)"
          }
        ],
        "recurring_deliveries": true,
        "price_adjustments": [
          {
            "order_count": null,
            "position": 1,
            "value_type": "percentage",
            "value": 0
          }
        ]
      },
      "checkout_charge_amount": 9500,
      "remaining_balance_charge_amount": 0
    }
  },
  { 
    "line_level_discount_allocations": [],
    "line_level_total_discount": 0
  }
]
```

I need to check if any of the `cart.items` has a `selling_plan_allocation`.

Would it be possible to do something like (pseudo code below)

- If any dictionary contains "selling_plan_allocation" -> do something
- If no dictionary in the array contains "selling_plan_allocation" -> do something else.

I would prefer to avoid having to loop over the list and checking each individual index. Is there some nifty shortcut?

E.g

```
{% if cart.items contains selling_plan_allocation %}
  array has at least one dictionary with `selling_plan_allocation`
{% else %}
  no dictionary has any `selling_plan_allocation`
{% endif %}
```

Perhaps there is a way better way, but the reason I'd like to check for any `selling_plan_allocation` is because I got a table like this:

```
<!-- if no `selling_plan_allocation` is found at all, don't render the table -->
<table>
  <thead>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {%- for item in cart.items -%}
      {% if item.selling_plan_allocation != nil %}
        <!-- my data here, <tr> and <td> etc -->
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

If no `selling_plan_allocation` is found, I don't want to render the table above at all, but if I put  the for loop outside the `<table>` part, it would make a new table for each cart item, when in reality I just want to loop through and only make one body - not one table

Comment: Does it have to be recursive...?

Comment: I updated the question to better reflect my reasoning

Comment: I think you're gonna have to do a loop and use `in` to check. There's really no way around it.

Comment: You are comparing JSON data to Liquid filtering? You have to settle on the right tool for the job here. If you want to filter JSON and cherry pick data, you use JS. If you just want to check for the presence of an attribute on a Liquid object, you get the good old if or case when etc in liquid.

Comment: That is liquid data, I just printed out `{{ cart.items | json }}` so it's easier to read. No one said anything about json itself :)